# Imagebutton not fading out

Tags: java, android, libgdx, imagebutton

I am working on screen fading in and out transition and currently my stage only consist of a background image and a image button (will have one more button in future). The problem now is the background fading work but not the imagebutton. Any idea how I can easily "group" the stage all together and fadeout all at once? This is my current code:

```
public class MyActor extends Actor {

    @Override
    public void draw( SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha ) {
        batch.setColor( 1, 1, 1, 1*parentAlpha );

        batch.draw( AssetLoader.bg, 0, 0, ZBGame.VIRTUAL_WIDTH, ZBGame.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT );

        batch.draw( AssetLoader.zbLogo,
                    ZBGame.VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2-140,
                    ZBGame.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT-AssetLoader.zbLogo.getRegionHeight(),
                    AssetLoader.zbLogo.getRegionWidth(),
                    AssetLoader.zbLogo.getRegionHeight());


        TextureAtlas buttons = new TextureAtlas( Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.txt") );
        Skin skin = new Skin( buttons );

        ImageButtonStyle btnStyle = new ImageButtonStyle();
        btnStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("startBtn");

        ImageButton button = new ImageButton(btnStyle);

        button.addListener(new InputListener( ) {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                stage.addAction( Actions.sequence( Actions.fadeOut(.5f), Actions.run( new Runnable( ) {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        game.setScreen(new OptionScreen( game ) );
                    }

                }) ) );
                return true;
            }
        stage.addActor(button);
    }
}

@Override
public void show() {
    stage = new Stage( );
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    MyActor myActor = new MyActor( );
    stage.addActor(myActor);
    stage.addAction( Actions.sequence( Actions.alpha(0), Actions.fadeIn(1)) );
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}
```

Comment: I remember some simmelar issue. Try setting the ImageButton color alpha before you add the listener. (to 1.0 or something)

Comment: Just tried adding button.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1.0f); but still doesn't work. The button fading in has no issue, only not fading out.

Comment: I've added button.setColor(1, 1, 1, parentAlpha ); and did a console output and it does decrease the alpha value after clicked but somehow the image just doesn't fadeout, it will just disappear once it reaches 0.0 Could this be a bug?

Comment: In your actor's draw method, you are creating a new ImageButton and adding it. So after one second at 60fps, there are 60 buttons, and so on until you run out of memory. So behavior is going to be unexpected. One of your buttons might be fading out, but the other few hundred buttons are not, so you still see them. Only create your actors and atlases once when the class is instantiated.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you so so much for pointing that out. I just refactor my code and its working fine now! But somehow I just don't understand why the ImageButton is being created like what you said for example 60times in 60fps while batch.draw doesn't draw 60 times?

Comment: The batch does draw 60 times a second. The `render` method in your Screen class is called for every frame (typically 60 times a second unless the game is not performing well). The render method calls `draw` on the Stage. The Stage calls `draw` on every actor. So `draw` is called 60 times a second. The `Gdx.gl.clear()` method is called at the beginning of your `render` method to erase everything so it can start over again on each frame.